# access to model specific registers, IA32_APERF / IA32_MPERF, to measure actual CPU frequency

Tags: timer, cpu, intel, frequency, privileges

As far as I understand to measure the actual operating CPU frequency I need access to the model specific registers (MSR) IA32_APERF and IA32_MPERF ([Assembly CPU frequency measuring algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65095/assembly-cpu-frequency-measuring-algorithm)).

However, access to the MSR registers is privileged (through the rdmsr instruction).  Is there another way this can be done?  I mean, for example, through a device driver/library which I could call in my code.  It seems strange to me that reading the registers is privileged.  I would think only writing to them would be privileged.

Note: the rdtsc instruction does not account for turbo boost and thus cannot report the actual operating frequency

Edit:
I'm interested in solutions for Linux and/or Windows.

Comment: What operating system ?

Comment: I am using Windows 7 and Linux but if I had a solution for either one that would be progress

Comment: For Linux see: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/msr.4.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are right, the proper way to find average cpu frequency described in 2nd answer in your link.
2. To read msrs on linux you can use tool [RDMSR](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/rdmsr.1.html).
3. The only thing that maybe missleading in that answer, is **maxfrequency**. It should be not maxfrequency, but nominal frequency (max non-turbo frequency), as MPERF counter counts in max-non turbo frequency. You can get this frequency from MSR 0xCE bits 8:15 ([ref](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf))

Comment: Thank you.  I was wondering about what to do with maxfrequency since it's part of what I am trying to determine.  Since it's really the nominal frequency I think I know what to do now.